# How to center a 3 column Css Div Site?

Tags: css, layout, html

My site has a 100% width header & footer, and 3 columns. The columns need to all be fixed width, but in the center of the page.

**HTML**

```
<div id="Table_01">
    <div id="Header"></div>
    <span id="LeftCol">Left Col </span>
    <span id="MidCol">Middle    </span>
    <span id="RightCol">Right Col   </span>
    <div id="Footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #Table_01 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
}    
#Header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:42px;
    background-image: url("images/Header.gif");
}
#LeftCol {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:42px;
    width:300px;
    height:422px;
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid;
}    
#MidCol {
    position:absolute;
    left:300px;
    top:42px;
    width:550px;
    height:422px;
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid;
}    
#RightCol {
    position:absolute;
    left:850px;
    top:42px;
    width:300px;
    height:422px;
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid;
}    
#Footer {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:464px;
    width:1000px;
    height:1536px;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ufuV/54/)

Comment: Calling the system stupid will not attract sympathy. You could just post your code here. Ctrl+V works well on SO ;)

Comment: If it's so stupid, go ask a question somewhere else, I prefer to see the code here before going to see it in action

Comment: It wont let me post the link without the code. If I add the code, it formats bad and still gives me the errors

Comment: <div id="Table_01">
    <div id="Header"></div> <span id="LeftCol">Left Col
 </span>
 <span id="MidCol">Middle
 </span>
 <span id="RightCol">Right Col
 </span>

    <div id="Footer">Footer</div>
</div>

Comment: Yes, it won't let you so that the question can be more self contained and more useful to others. SO is not just to solve your problems, it's also to help others in the future. Having the code here makes it much easier (not as a comment, make your question look nice)

Comment: I pasted the code within the "Insert code here", and half the code went in bold, some ended up outside the code section, and then gave errors when posting.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "in the center of the page"...it is possible to center the middle column but there are many other possibilities for where the other two columns could be relative to the space on the page. What goal do you want to achieve with respect to these columns?

Comment: This was 8 years ago (before I knew how to ask questions). I believe I just wanted to center the site rather than it be off to the left. No longer needed. Wrapping it in a container as per the answer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a mix of `position:relative` and `margin:0 auto` applied to a container.

Add a container div:

```
.container {
    width:1150px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

See updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8ufuV/56/)

Comment: Thanks for giving an actual answer. This worked, Although I placed after the header to only center the 3 columns so header is stretched across. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, adapt as needed ;)